# Write last three entries per name in a file

Tags: python, csv

I have the following data in a file:

```
Sarah,10
John,5
Sarah,7
Sarah,8
John,4
Sarah,2
```

I would like to keep the last three rows for each person.  The output would be:

```
John,5
Sarah,7
Sarah,8
John,4
Sarah,2
```

In the example, the first row for Sarah was removed since there where three later rows.  The rows in the output also maintain the same order as the rows in the input.  How can I do this?

Additional Information
You are all amazing - Thank you so much. Final code which seems to have been deleted from this post is -

```
import collections

with open("Class2.txt", mode="r",encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    count = collections.defaultdict(int)
    rev = reversed(fp.readlines())
    rev_out = []

    for line in rev:
        name, value = line.split(',')
        if count[name] >= 3:
            continue
        count[name] += 1
        rev_out.append((name, value))

out = list(reversed(rev_out))

print (out)
```

Comment: Is it required to do this in python?

Comment: This question seems pretty broad. It will be better if you can share some logic/code/research that you've come up with that you are having troubles implementing in Python.

Comment: Are there more entries in the file? What's the reason the first Sarah needs to be removed but not the last Sarah?

Comment: I see three main parts: reading the file, keeping track of names (a dictionary would do the trick) and storing at most three pieces of information about them (I would use a queue for that). Do you have specific questions? Own code?

Comment: @Daniel "keep the last three entries"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks like csv data, use the `csv` module to read and write it.  As you read each line, store the rows grouped by the first column.  Store the line number along with the row so that they can be written out maintaining the same order as the input.  Use a bound deque to keep only the last three rows for each name.  Finally, sort the rows and write them out.

```
import csv

by_name = defaultdict(lambda x: deque(x, maxlen=3))

with open('my_data.csv') as f_in
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f_in)):
        by_name[row[0]].append((i, row))

# sort the rows for each name by line number, discarding the number
rows = sorted(row[1] for value in by_name.values() for row in value, key=lambda row: row[0])

with open('out_data.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    csv.writer(f_out).writerows(rows)
```